# How to properly import custom icons created with IcoMoon in react native component (expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have created custom icons. If I try to use the icons in App.js it works fine. I want to use them in my other files. What is the proper way of doing it?

```
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Icon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
  require("./components/SVGComponents/selection.json"),
  "IcoMoon",
  "icomoon.ttf"
);

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    ...

    //icons font
    IcoMoon: require("./components/SVGComponents/icomoon.ttf"),
  });
};


export default function App() {
  const [isFontLoaded, setIsFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  if (!isFontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setIsFontLoaded(true)}
        }
      />
    );
  }
...
}
```

I tried creating an Icon component, importing it in the App.js file and then using it in other component of mine but I am getting the following errors :

> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

> AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
//Icon.js
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from "@expo/vector-icons";


const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
   ...

    //icons font
    IcoMoon: require("./components/SVGComponents/icomoon.ttf"),
  });
};

export default Icon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
  require("./components/SVGComponents/selection.json"),
  "IcoMoon",
  "icomoon.ttf"
);
```

```
//in App.js
import Icon from "./components/SVGComponents/Icon";
```

Also tried with export const Icon and import {Icon} , got the same error

in the component i want to use icons:

```
<Icon name="Back" color="green" size={44}></Icon>
```

What did the job - exporting Icon from App.js and importing it in the component I want to use it like that:

```
import { Icon } from "../../App";
```

but I am not sure it's a good idea to use it this way. How would you suggest I use it?

Comment: I my experiencie, I had a few problems with icomoon (very long proccess to add icon to an icon set, icomoon doesnt support two colors icons, so much dependency of the lib), I would recommend you try avoid this lib.. You can use rect-native-svg and render your svgs, taking control of size, color, animation for example of your icons

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
//Icon.js
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from "react-native-vector-icons";

export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
  require("./selection.json"),
  "IcoMoon",
  "icomoon.ttf"
);
```

In the file I want to use the icon:

`import Icon from "../SVGComponents/Icon";`

Then

```
//App.js
const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
 

    //icons font
    IcoMoon: require("./components/SVGComponents/icomoon.ttf"),
  });
};



export default function App() {
  const [isFontLoaded, setIsFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  if (!isFontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setIsFontLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) =>
          console.log("App => fetchFonts,  <AppLoading> => " + err)
        }
      />
    );

   ...
  }
```

in a folder called SVGComponents I have placed the icon font file - icomoon.ttf, the icons - selection.json, the custom icon component - Icon.js